# Is there a possibility to print just 1 byte of a string?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I mean is there a possibility to print a string like ("hello") to i.e. just "e" or "l".
I thought i could accomplish that with this code:

```
char *gg = "hello";
printf("%.4s \n",gg + strlen(gg) - 2);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to just change "%.4s \n" into "%c \n"  and dereference the (gg + strlen(gg) - 1) with *.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani: I think you mean `"%.1s"`. You need `%s` for strings (which `gg + strlen(gg) - 2` is) and `"%c"` for characters.

Comment: @pmg Ok %s for string but you want 1 byte from it so you need %c. in C when you say print %s  you mean go and read string until \0 and when you say print %c you mean just print one character.

Comment: No! `%c` expects a value of type `int`, `%s` expects a value of type `char *`. These types are not compatible. You cannot interchange them willy-niilly

Comment: @pmg I now understand what you mean and I correct my first comment. sorry.

Comment: Now it's ok. Good correction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to do the following:

```
char *gg = "hello";
printf( "%c\n", gg[3] );
```

This will print the fourth character (zero based array = 0, 1, 2, 3  so 0='h', 1='e', etc). Change the 3 to which ever character you want, but make sure to not go past the end of the string. strlen will tell you the length of the string.

Comment: OP asked for the `e` or the `l` but as there are two of `l`, the answer would be clearer on the `e` which would be `gg[1]` (although his code was trying for `gg[3]`).

Comment: I interpreted the OP's question using 'e' or 'l' as just examples of a single character. My answer gives the last 'l' like his strlen() - 2 suggested. I guess if the character was important the code would have to search for it, but that wouldn't make sense.